# facebook isSessionValid is always NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

hi i use the newest facebook api  with SSO and do implement like following in my viewController (not in the appDelegate like in the example if that makes any difference):
in my .h file

```
Facebook *facebook;
@property (nonatomic,retain) Facebook *facebook;
```

in my .m file i do the following in my viewDidLoad

```
self.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"myappID"];
```

in another method I do

```
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {


NSArray *permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",nil] retain];
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
}
```

but it seems that isSessionValid is alway NO 
and I don't know why!
does anybody have any idea why ?
oh and also expirationDate and accessTokken are nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

alright here is the answer to my problem.
as I said in the comment also the application:handleOpenURL: never got called!
cause I had this method in my ViewController and apparently it has to be in the appDelegate!

so in my Navigationbar based application I did the following in my appDelegate:

in the .h file:

```
ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;
```

in the .m file:

```
@synthesize viewController;

viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

and then implemented the method like that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

return [viewController.facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

and of course in my ViewController I did everything @Tyler mentioned (thank you for that)
and everything works like a charm.
hope this helps everyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem yesterday, it seems you must persist and restore the access token/expiration date yourself.

In your viewDidLoad:

```
// Restore previously saved Facebook credentials (If any)
facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FBAccessToken"];
facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDate"];

// Trigger SSO Facebook authentication if required
if ([facebook isSessionValid] == NO) {
    [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
} else {
    [self fbDidLogin];
}
```

Then in the fbDidLogin delegate:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin
```

{
    // Save the users access token and expiration date so we can restore it later
    // This way we can avoid needlessly authenticating to Facebook.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.facebook.accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"FBExpirationDate"];

// User has logged in to Facebook, now get their userId from Facebook
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

}

So now users will have to login/authorize your application once and from then on their session will remain valid until they logout of Facebook.

Comment: thanks for your hint. sounds very reasonable. but it also seems my - (void)fbDidLogin is never get called for what ever reason! I have not implemented all this in my appdelegate instead I did in in my mainViewController is this a problem ?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set up the URLScheme correctly if the SSO isn't redirecting to your app and calling the fbDidLogin delegate. Have a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ "iOS for iPhone/iPad" section.

Comment: I did it with this document. and I have set that. looks totally the same except I have a URL Identifier in there but the example app has exactly like I do.

Comment: i have it now the same way but it does not work.... I also found that - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
 
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
} which is implemented in my viewController class is never called

Comment: alright I got it. I voted your answer up cause it is part of the answer but did not quite do the trick for me to work. But with my answer and your answer everything works like a charm. thank you a lot

Comment: @Tyler how did you get and display the userId from Facebook? thanks